# How to use Dev tools which flashes momentary pink rectangle on any screen sections being redrawn?

Tags: android

How to use Dev tools which flashes momentary pink rectangle on any screen sections being redrawn?

Tool description is given at
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html

Could anybody please suggest me where to install this tool and how to use it?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 3):

Emulator has a package named Dev tools installed.

Go to : Dev Tools -> devlopment Settings -> check show screen updates.

This will show all the repaints in pink.

Comment: ok, searched so hard, didn't occur to me it was app on the emulator! :):)

Comment: Thanks Samuh, but i could not find Dev tools where exactly it is?